# Varnish proxy for s3 bucket fails to sign REST calls with parameters in URL

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, varnish, varnish-vcl, varnish-4

Im implementing Varnish HTTP proxy to serve content from S3 bucket.
The content is very big JS client 2K+ files.
I found out this guide
https://info.varnish-software.com/blog/using-varnish-cache-secured-aws-s3-gateway

In general it signs http requests and redirects them to s3 endpoint

```
sub vcl_backend_fetch
{
  set bereq.http.Host = "bucket.s3.amazonaws.com";
  set bereq.http.Date = now;

  set bereq.http.NL = {"
"};

  set bereq.http.Authorization = "AWS YOURVERYLONGACCESSID:" +
    digest.base64_hex(digest.hmac_sha1("somelongvalueforsecret",
      bereq.method + bereq.http.NL + bereq.http.Content-MD5 + bereq.http.NL +
      bereq.http.Content-Type + bereq.http.NL + bereq.http.Date + bereq.http.NL + 
      "/" + "bucket" + bereq.url
    ));

  unset bereq.http.NL;
}
```

It work for retrieving files, however if i have http parameters in url i want to fetch it fails with error `SignatureDoesNotMatch`.

Comment: My environment : varnish-6.0.6 docker from official docker-hub repo.

Comment: Doesn't the error message contain a lot more information, like a Canonical Request and String to Sign?

Answer (score 0):

The blog post from my colleague Reza dates back to 2016. Chances are that AWS has already changed the signing algorithm.

We have updated *VCL code* that works on AWS S3 right now, but it's part of our enterprise offering, and uses some of our enterprise *VMODs*.

If you're interested, you can spin up one of our [official Varnish Enterprise images on AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B07L7HVVMF?ref_=srh_res_product_title), which doesn't require you to purchase a license in advance. See https://docs.varnish-software.com/varnish-cache-plus/vmods/aws/ for more information.

But if you insist on doing this using *Varnish Cache*, I suggest you have a look at the S3 API spec, and adjust the signing yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The code that i was using was outdated.
I needed to sign my requests with sig4 version of AWS REST API.
This repo was helpful:

https://github.com/xcir/libvmod-awsrest

IMPORTANT: be carefull if you url contain special symbols @ & [] etc. In my case signature was failing because i had [ and ] symbols in name of the files. Ive replaced them

```
set bereq.url = regsuball(bereq.url,"\[","%5B");
set bereq.url = regsuball(bereq.url,"\]","%5D");
```

and it worked.